# Unrecognized selector when populating an NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an iPad app using Core Data. In my data model I have an object called HubBrand and have generated NSManagedObects using XCode. The generated object has the following code:

Header:

```
@class HubModel;

@interface HubBrand : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * brandName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *relModels;
@end

@interface HubBrand (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addRelModelsObject:(HubModel *)value;
- (void)removeRelModelsObject:(HubModel *)value;
- (void)addRelModels:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeRelModels:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation HubBrand

@dynamic brandName;
@dynamic relModels;

@end
```

I am trying to create an instance of the HubBrand class and populate it using the foloowing code:

```
HubBrand *brand = [[HubBrand alloc] init];
[brand setBrandName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_Custom:, %@", [_txtHubBrand text]]];
//brand.brandName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_Custom:, %@", [_txtHubBrand text]];
```

When I do so, I get the following runtime error:
-[HubBrand setBrandName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

When using generated managed objects, am I required to implement my own setters? Any clues as to why I am getting this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a sub class of a [`NSManagedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) using a [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectContext) based on its [`NSEntityDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; // Get this from your Core Data stack, probably in the app delegate
HubBrand *brand = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HubBrand" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[brand setBrandName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_Custom:, %@", [_txtHubBrand text]]];
```

See the [*Creating, Initializing, and Saving a Managed Object*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-CJBDBHCB) section of the doc for more info.

You can also use the sub classes initializer:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HubBrand" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
HubBrand *brand = [[HubBrand alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

But its a bit more wordy!

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the designated initializer for `NSManagedObject`, so you're not getting valid objects. You can't create instances using `init`, you have to use `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. It's also possible to use the constructor on `NSEntityDescription` called `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`.